# Bing translate, licensing for shareware

Tags: licensing, translate, bing

I've got a small program which I'd like to offer online, either for free or for a small amount (£5/£10 perhaps). However it revolves around Bing translate. What would be the licensing position for that? Can't tell if it's free or not.

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look into the [Bing API Terms of Use](http://www.bing.com/developers/tou.aspx) to see wether you can do with the Bing API results.

Accordingly with point 2 of the [ToU](http://www.bing.com/developers/tou.aspx) failing to specify otherwise, you can use the Bing API for commercial purposes in your websites and applications:

> 2.- **WHAT RIGHTS DO I HAVE?**  Solely to the extent that you are in compliance with all terms of this Agreement, we grant you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, non-sublicenseable license to use the services to: enable your Website or application to obtain Bing results; make limited intermediate copies of the Bing results, solely as necessary to display them on your Website or application; and host and display Bing results on your Website or application.  Your license to use the services is limited, however, to solely your Websites and applications.  You are responsible for your own conduct and content while using the services and for any consequences of this use.  All queries to the Bing services that you provide must be user initiated and refineable by the user.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: From that it sounds like it's free. I'll assume it is. Thanks